# Using different text and math fonts with unicode-math

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, unicode-math

When using pdfLaTeX it is sometimes possible, when using different text and math font sets, to take the fonts for operators like `sin` and `cos` from the text font even within formulae. Thus, using the `lucimatx` package, I can write

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch}
\usepackage[onlymath=true]{lucimatx}
```

and then formulae will be set using `lucida` for math fonts, but charter (i.e., `bch`) for text-like objects like `sin` and `cos`, so matching the text using in the document body. This is what one wants from a typographic standpoint.

Is something similar possible using `unicode-math`? If I use

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}   % Charis is a charter clone
\setmathfont{LucidaBrightMathOT.otf}
```

It seems to use `lucida` fonts for everything in math mode. The same if I use `xits` math fonts. I may, of course, be missing the equivalent of the `onlymath` option in `unicode-math`. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Geoff Vallis

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: if you indent lines by four spaces, they will be autoformatted as LaTeX code.

Comment: Thanks for the edits and the hints. I'm new to TeX.SE (and to unicode-math).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not really sure you want to mix Charis SIL and Lucida Bright Math. However, here's the workaround you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}   % Charis is a charter clone
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{LucidaBrightMathOT.otf}
\setmathfont[range={`A-`Z,`a-`z}]{Charis SIL}

\begin{document}
sin $\sin x=y$ \textit{x}
\end{document}
```

The “sin” outside the formula is just to show that Charis SIL is really used for the operator. The trailing italic “x” is for comparing with the math mode “x”.

You'll get warnings such as

```
Font 'Charis SIL' does not contain script 'Math'.
```

that are unavoidable. Note the `Scale` option for loading Lucida Bright Math.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your solution almost works but not quite because upright operators like \nabla need to be taken from the original math font and not the text font. Building on your code it seems that a working solution mimicking the 'onlymath' option is:

    \documentclass{article}  
    \usepackage{unicode-math}  
    \setmainfont{Charis SIL}   % Charis is a charter clone  
    \setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{LucidaBrightMathOT.otf}  
    \setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin,num}]{Charis SIL}  
 
    \begin{document}  
    sin $\sin x=y $ \textit{x} and $\nabla x = 123$123  
    \end{document}

Comment: @Geoff Check with the new version.

Comment: @egeg Or, to get the numbers in the text font: 
    \setmathfont[range={`A-`Z,`a-`z,`1-`9}]{Charis SIL}  

(I haven't figured out the proper formatting in posts yet, sorry!)

Comment: I guess that `range=\mathup/{latin,Latin,num}` is the best approach.

Comment: Yes I agree. I consider this question answered and will so mark it if I can figure that out...

Comment: It seems that in some cases one needs to add an additional line to your solution along the lines of:  `\setmathfont[range={\mathit->\mathit}]{LucidaBrightMathOT.otf}`  as the last line. This needs to be done  so that the positions of some math characters are correct, as they seem to be taken from the OpentType Math table using last font mentioned. Without it, the positions of hats and tildes is incorrect.